# Linux kernel's list.h

Tags: c, linux

Where can I find the infamous list.h from the linux kernel?

I remember seeing it at once point and I can't for the life of me find it again. I'm running a Windows box so it would be great if you can point me out to a nice HTTP site where it's hosted :)

Thanks.

Comment: Why is it infamous? Just because it's an intrusive list node? I've seen tricksier in C, for instance a "generic" list. To use it you #define a few macros including the type of the payload, and then #include a header. I think you could even #include it multiple times to create multiple "instantiations".

Comment: flaged. 1) There is no list.c in linux kernel. 2) list.h is good. not infamous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [here](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/) for details about the Linux `list.h`.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a peek at the code, the [Linux Cross Reference](http://lxr.linux.no/) will show you anything you like.  I don't see a `list.c` in there anywhere, though.

Comment: It's the kernel's linked list implementation.

Comment: The linked list helpers are macros, and contained in list.h